# Can we compute the mean of indefinite interval of a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

To be more specific, can we compute  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\int e^{-x^2}dxdx $ .

The beginning of this question is:

I've read a paper trying to calculate $\int{P(x_t|x_{t-1})P(x_{t-1}|y)}dx_{t-1}$  while $P(x_t|x_{t-1})$ and $ P(x_{t-1}|y) $ are both Gaussian. Although the writer said this could be compute analytically and exactly, I think the indefinite integral could not be caculate. So I tried to reanalyse the whole derivative process and found that only the mean and covariance of the integral are needed. But I cannot find information about the mean and covariance of the integral of Gaussian on search engine. So I resort for help here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gaussian describes a single random variable. How are $y$, $x_{t-1}$, and $x_t$ jointly related?

Comment: your integral is divergent, because the integrand does not vanish as $x\to\infty$

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{\mathbb R} x F(x)dx$, where $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2}dt$?

Comment: @aschepler the two Gaussian distributions are conditional distribution. For example, in the first Guassian, $x_t$ is the random variable and $x_{t-1}$ is the condition. In fact the first distribution is $x_t \sim N(Ax_{t-1}+b,Q)$ while A, b and Q are constant.

Comment: @kimchilover yes

Comment: Obviously divergent.  For $x>0$ your integrand is bounded below by $xF(0)$.